# How do you find the scythe in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

How do you get the scythe in Terraria? I've looked through out my whole world of Terraria, but yet have not found one.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool or a weapon ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, no guarantee that any given magic item definitely exists in a particular world.

Comment: That statement may apply for items in chests (gold, shadow, etc...) and weapons that comes out of corruption or crimson.  But the magic spell "demon scythe" can be obtained an infinite amount of time whatever the situation.

Answer (score 8):

There are some weapons that contains "scythe" or "sickle" in their name, here is the way to get them :

#### [Demon scythe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Scythe)

Magical weapon that attacks the same way as the demons in the underworld (A.K.A. : hell)
Dropped by demons or voodoo demons in the underworld, with a 2% chance of loot.

#### [Ice sickle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ice_Sickle)

Melee weapon, launch an icy projectile while swinging it.
Dropped by armored vikings, they spawn in hardmode ice caves. The chance of drop is 0.5%.

#### [Death sickle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Death_Sickle)

Melee weapon, launch a multi-hitting projectile, and autoswings.
Dropped by reapers, they spawn during a solar eclipse, and the chance of drop is 0.4%.

If you're looking for the objects named [scythe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Scythe), or [soul scythe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Soul_Scythe), know that these items have been removed from the game, as for the version 1.2.4.

If you didn't looked for weapons, but for a scythe-type tool, there is one :

#### [Sickle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sickle)

Produces hay blocks upon harvesting grass.
Bought from the merchant NPC, **only during halloween**, at the price of **1** gold coin.

If you want this item now, you can change your internal date to match the halloween specifications : set the day between **October 20th** and **November 10th**

Comment: There's also the sickle which is bought from the merchant during Halloween. It is a tool rather than a weapon but it could fit in the list.

Comment: Good point @Nick, it might be the item the asker was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The scythe is a deleted weapon, the game devs added it but then got rid of it. So for now it is impossible to get it even if you use cheats, if you do use cheats it will turn into an angel statue.